# SQL Update Query Issue #1054

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I don't code often and am stuck on something that should be simple. I'm trying the following:

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` 
SET `class-count` = class-count+1 
WHERE user_id = 7
```

but am getting an error unknown column for class count. `Class-count` is the record identifier in the column `meta_key` and the `user_id` is in the column `meta_key` as well.

What am I doing wrong? I just want to be able to enter the `user_id` into a text field on a form and update the `class-count` by 1 on each submission.

Comment: class minus count  plus 1... You forgot to delimit!

Comment: Are you sure that `class-count` is `class-count` not `class_count` ??

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Smith, please check the column name i.e. `class-count`. Because SQL will not accept like `class-count`, it should be like `class_count`.

Comment: Or perhaps back-tick class-count back-tick.

Answer (score 0):

In sql columns to separate two words `_` should be used instead of `-`. So try to use `class_count`. 
Other thing is that `count` is reserved keyword for sql so you can write like this

```
[classcount]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `class-count` = `class-count`+1 WHERE 
user_id =7
```